# Should a rollback on a suggested edit remove reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

I recently suggested an edit, and it was approved. I got the +2 on reputation. But since I made some mistake it was rolled back. But I still retained the +2 reputation.

Should I be having a -2 to my reputation since the suggested edit was not approved?

Here is the link to [said post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24814122/3).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back Also, how about that, for once we actually have an editor who agrees - and even expects - that their +2 rep be reverted when their approved edit is later rolled back.

Comment: Now we've got some moderators around, anyone fancy banning the ridiculous reviewers who approved the edit (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5333111) in the first place?

Comment: @Matt: I've seen worse than that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Then ban them as well. It doesn't make the accepting of this edit right.

Comment: @Matt: what is amusing is that even the people rejecting it did not click the correct reject reason.

Answer (score 20):

## Yes!

Rolling back is only used in the circumstance that the edit shouldn't have been approved. If it shouldn't have been approved, there shouldn't be a rep award. Additionally, it means that the approvers of it were wrong and a review ban should be considered (auto-flag raise?).

Yes, people might hunt for bad editors and do mass-rollbacks. Oh noes! That might improve post quality and catch robo-approvers!

No, using rollbacks as an attack is not going to happen because a) you need 2k to rollback b) bumping it to the homepage so other people notice is not a good idea, and c) downvoting is a more obvious option.

Comment: Should a rollback of the rollback get the +2 back, and should the rollback of the rollback of the rollback remove +2 again?  This idea is just a recipe for disaster.  Rather that bitching about someone getting a +2, mods should be able to [ban users from suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

Comment: @psubsee Yes, yes. How? Why not both?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It looks like [minitech's bounty worked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits#comment776142_221832).

Comment: +1 to the answer, although I do not necessarily agree with the optimism of the last paragraph. I would rather see the solution in peer review for the revert. Also, downvoting is more obvious, but you have a limit there for the automated serial vote detection, combining that with another possibility is even more obvious when the revenge is happening unless this factor is also built into the "serial-downvoting-catch" logic.

Comment: That being said, prevention might make more sense than circumventing the original issue: crappy edits.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think so.  The 2 points is awarded based on review approvals, not on the edit maintaining its present state for all time.

Comment: +1 People would start hunting for bad editors and rolling back their posts. Recipe for disaster.

Comment: @user000001 Or worse still hunting out good editors and rolling back the edits out of spite.

Comment: @Servy: Heard that so often, ever actually happened? Or is there strong evidence it will happen, and won't easily be caught? Remember it needs 2000+ reputation...

Comment: @Deduplicator Well there'd be no point in doing it now, as it wouldn't actually harm the editor.  It would be a type of abuse that would become viable if and only if this feature were added.

Comment: @Servy: Which leaves the question if it will be easily caught and corrected. And that one is the crucial one for abuse potential. We already stop people nuking their contributions (i.e. on rage-quit)...

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, that is indeed a factor.  There would need to be some way of drawing attention to the fact that this was going on so that abuse would be able to be detected and reversed.  it doesn't mean the feature can't exist at all, but it does mean some safeguards may need to be in place to mitigate the potential abuse.

Comment: `not on the edit maintaining its present state for all time` .. or even a few minutes. When a bad edit is approved and that edit is caught a few minutes later (followed by a rollback), I don't think the editor should be rewarded with rep. I came here after running into an editor who was bolding the text in questions, getting those edits approved, and farming the rep. The edits were clearly "no improvement".

Answer (score 1):

It should... but it allows things like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46093144/revisions

Where someone rollback your edit by accident and you lose your reputation points.

Comment: Hey there. It might seem un-obvious, but that person did not get "your" reputation points. One never gets points for editing their own post. Moreover, that user is also fairly new, and as original poster of the post you edited, they get a binding vote on what happens. They very well could have simply clicked without really knowing what they were doing. Nothing bad happened here, and it's almost certainly wrong to presume of their intentions.

Comment: True, they just removed the reputation points without gaining any. Thanks Félix.  They probably didn't mean any harm and did it by mistake.  At least he fixed the broken link, that's what matters.